# Symptom spark Multi-partition read mysql data througth dataFrame and performs join operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There are two mysql tables,now I use spark multi-partition parallel reading these two tables separately and construct two dataFrame, then I use these two dataFrame to join , the following error was received

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 19796,4949)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2011)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**My Scala Code looks like this:**

```
object TestJoin {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
      InitSparkEnv.init(args(0), "local[*]")
    } else {
      InitSparkEnv.initNotSupportHive(args(0))
    }
    val ssc = InitSparkEnv.getSparkSession

    val tableName_goods = "data_center_cdm.dwd_cob_mc_enterprise_goods"
    val tableName_goods_attr = "data_center_cdm.dwd_cob_mc_enterprise_goods_attr"

    ConnUtil.initMysql()
    val prop = ConnUtil.getProp
    val readFromMysql = new ReadFromMysql(ssc, prop)
    // 5 partitions read in parallel
    val goods = readFromMysql.getDataByPage(prop.getProperty("url"), tableName_goods, 5)
    val goods_attr = readFromMysql.getDataByPage(prop.getProperty("url"), tableName_goods_attr, 5)
    
    val result = goods.join(goods_attr, "goods_md5")
    result.show(false)
    ssc.stop()
  }
}

class ReadFromMysql(ssc: SparkSession) extends Serializable {
 
    private val NUM_PARTITIONS = 20
    private val MAX_FETCH_SIZE = 100

    /**
     *
     * @param url       url
     * @param tableName tableName 
     * @param pageNum   PartitionNum
     */
    def getDataByPage(url: String, tableName: String, pageNum: Int): DataFrame = {
      // 查询该表的数量级
      val query_sql = s"(select count(*) from ${tableName}) tbl"
      val tableRows = getData(url, query_sql)
      val tableNumRecords = tableRows.head().get(0).asInstanceOf[Long]
      if (tableNumRecords <= MAX_FETCH_SIZE) {
        getData(url, tableName)
      } else {
        val usePartNum = if (pageNum > NUM_PARTITIONS) {
          logger.warn("user defined num-partitions:" + pageNum + ",but max partitions is " + NUM_PARTITIONS)
          min(pageNum, NUM_PARTITIONS)
        } else {
          logger.info("user defined num-partitions:" + pageNum + "")
          pageNum
        }
        val predicates: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer[String]()
        val setupNums = tableNumRecords / usePartNum
        val remainder = tableNumRecords - (setupNums * usePartNum)
        logger.info("The number of data pulled each time is " + setupNums)
        for (num <- 0 until usePartNum) {
          predicates += "1=1 limit " + setupNums * num + "," + setupNums
        }
        predicates += "1=1 limit " + (setupNums * usePartNum) + "," + remainder

        ssc.read.jdbc(url, tableName, predicates.toArray, prop)
      }
    }
}
```

There is also a solution to the above problem,which is to cache the two dataFrame before joining them,like this:

```
   ... 
   
    // 5 partitions read in parallel
    val goods = readFromMysql.getDataByPage(prop.getProperty("url"), tableName_goods, 5)
    val goods_attr = readFromMysql.getDataByPage(prop.getProperty("url"), tableName_goods_attr, 5)
        
    goods.cache()
    goods_attr.cache()

    val result = goods.join(goods_attr, "goods_md5")
    result.show(false)
    ssc.stop()
```

**when I use Single partition read mysql table data, there is no such problem,like this follow code:**

```
/**
 *
 * @param url       url
 * @param tableName tableMane
 * @return
 */
def getData(url: String, tableName: String): DataFrame = {
  logger.warn(s"this method read data just by one precess,start reading table [${tableName}] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
  ssc.read.jdbc(url, tableName, prop)
}
```

I don't understand why that is,Could it be a bug in spark? no,I don't think this.

The problem was solved when I tried to cache the two tables I read,but I knew it wasn't the final solution because I didn't understand how it worked.
I hope to get the rationale. please give me some suggestion，thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you're trying to slice the data into partitions.

See MySQL Limit keyword [description](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_limit.asp):

> The LIMIT clause is used to specify the number of records to return.

It's one number, not a range. It's also picking rows at random.

In this line:

```
predicates += "1=1 limit " + setupNums * num + "," + setupNums
```

You're dynamically creating a text for a MySQL query, but the query you're creating has incorrect syntax - trying to `limit` a range of rows, which isn't possible.

In general to make what you're trying to do work, you don't need to dynamically create any sql, the functionality exist in spark's read jdbc function. To do that just provide `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound` and `numPartitions` arguments. You can see the description of these here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html